# how to get the flags that chrome was launched with

Tags: automation, puppeteer

so am launching connection a puppeteer instances to an already opened chrome and then logging in to my Gmail account, as you know if I used the same user-data-dir. it would launch with an already signed in Gmail account, what I want to do is automatically harvester the user-data-dir from  the chrome instances so I can use them after a while, so I don't want to manually enter chrome://version to get it
am connecting puppeteer to chrome in this way :

```
const browserURL = `http://127.0.0.1:${port}`;
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL, defaultViewport : null });
const page = await browser.newPage();
```